# How do I use the azure msal library to access azure service management apis?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

All of the examples on the microsoft azure site having to do with a client application or a service principal having access to azure apis all show the graph apis as the example.
I got those to work, but what I need to do is access the azure service management apis.

If I take an auth token that works for the graph api and use it for the service management api, I get an "Authentication failed." error.

I have added the api permission for "azure service management" and the user_impersonation delegated permission type to my public client app, but the management apis still fail.

Am I going about this all wrong?
I get the idea that the service management apis are authenticated a different way since there's absolutely no mention of using them anywhere in any of the auth examples.

Comment: Show your code and the endpoints used for authentication.

Comment: The token for Graph API won't work. You need to get a token for the Azure API by specifying the correct scope/resource.

Comment: If I understand correctly you're trying to execute Service Management API for a Service Principal. Is this correct?

Comment: probably? I'm not 100% on all of the security concepts yet. I need consent from an admin in tenant A so my app in  tenant B can call vm/network/storage rest apis in tenant A. As I understand it a service principal is created in tenant A when consent is given to my tenant B app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are using the client application or a service principal to access azure resources. If so, you are using the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), but the `user_impersonation` of `Azure Service Management` API is a `delegated` permission, it will not take effect in this flow.

The permission is used to be consent by the user who login to the AD App e.g. in the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), when it has been consent by the user, the App will be able to represent the user to access the azure resources, note the permission is from the user, not the app. So if you want to use this flow,  the user should have a role in the subscription or specific resources.

To access the azure resources with the client application or a service principal, you just need to add the service principal as an RBAC role in the `Access control (IAM)` of your subscription or specific resource, no need to add any API permission in Azure AD, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal). Then the service principal will be able to access the azure resources.

When you getting the token to access the azure resources, e.g. call the REST APIs, the scope should be `https://management.azure.com/.default`, not the `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`, you can just get the token for one resource in one time.

Comment: The question is about invoking "Service Management API". Your answer is perfect for "Resource Manager API".

Comment: @GauravMantri Hi, if you navigate to an AD App -> API permission -> add permission, find the `Service Management API`, notice the resource url, you will find that actually is the `Resource Manager API` you mean.:-)

Comment: The resource URL is same for both (https://management.core.windows.net/) but Service Management API (for classic resources) work differently than Resource Manager API (for newer resources).

Comment: okay thanks, this is very helpful. I was able yesterday to get a little farther. All this stuff is at work and I'm home now so I can't show you exactly what I've got right now, but when you say this: `access the azure resources with the client application or a service principal, you just need to add the service principal as an RBAC role` I should have mentioned, I believe I need an app because I want to access resources in a completely different tenant. So I couldn't just use a service principal because that has to be created by the tenant admin, right?

Comment: If I understand right, I need the admin on the customer's side to grant my client app authority to use azure rest apis on the admin's behalf and they have to consent to letting me use the permissions I ask for on their account/tenant, right? I was using this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code where it says "request an authorization code". Is that correct?

Comment: @stu Yes, basically correct. If I did't misunderstand you, you are developing a app, when the user who is in a different tenant log in, he can access his azure resources, right? If so, you just need to create a [multi-tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps), give the `user_impersonation` permission in `azure service management` API which you used before.

Comment: @stu Then when the user login the app, it will ask the user to consent the permission, after the consent(whether the user has the permission to consent, it depends on your customer's tenant setting, by default, the `user_impersonation` does not need admin consent), your app will be able to represent him to access his azure resources.

Comment: perfect thanks. that's what I thought was going on and that's what I'm shooting for. appreciate the help. I may be back, but for now, I'm good. thanks.

Comment: so I eventually found this, and followed it and got it all working...   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow